# How to link a google cloud vm to an instance schedule?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I want to run my google cloud server everyday on specific times. I set up an instance schedule for that but when i try to link my vm to the schedule it gives me the following error:

```
Compute Engine System service account service-390738840624@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com needs to have [compute.instances.start] permissions applied in order to perform this operation.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service account **service-390738840624@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com** does not have a role with the permission **compute.instances.start**.

The following IAM roles have the required permission:

- roles/compute.instanceAdmin
- roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1

The following command will add the first role to the service account:

Replace $PROJECT_ID with your Project ID (not the project name).

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
--member serviceAccount:service-390738840624@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/compute.instanceAdmin
```

Your account for which you are running the command, must have the privilege to grant/modify IAM roles on a service account. If you do not have the correct permissions, you will need to ask the Project Owner or Editor to perform this for you.

Comment: Verified that this is the right solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The CLI answer works but in case you dont use terminal here are the steps directly on the platform:

1. go to IAM
2. on the right side of the screen select "Include Google-provided role grants"
3. Find Principal that contain text "compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
4. edit (with little pen on the right)
5. from the popup shown select "+Add another role", select role "Compute Instance Admin" (can show beta or v1 in the brackets)

this fixed my issue

Comment: That 'Google-provided role grants' filter was critical. I just spent so long trying to figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete the task, GCP is asking you to give the service account **“service-390738840624@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com”** access to use **“compute.instances.start”** but the service account doesn't have the right permissions to execute the task.

> When you set up an instance to run as a service account, you determine
> the level of access the service account has by the IAM roles that you
> grant to the service account. If the service account has no IAM roles,
> then no API methods can be run by the service account on that
> instance.

To grant, change, and revoke access to a single service account, please refer to [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/manage-access-service-accounts?hl=en).

Be aware that to manage access to a service account, you need a role that includes the following permissions:

- *iam.serviceAccounts.get
- iam.serviceAccounts.list
- iam.serviceAccounts.getIamPolicy
- iam.serviceAccounts.setIamPolicy*

If you want to know which are the permission included in your account, please refer to [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/viewing-users-and-permissions).

If you don't have the appropriate access to grant permissions, please refer to your system administrator.

To know more about compute engine roles and permissions, please [follow this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute_admin_role).

If you wish to know more about services accounts, please [follow this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts).

To know more about the process of scheduling compute instances with Google Scheduler, please [follow this link](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule).